# Jquery date give error when ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

Jquery give error after hosting application but work fine when debug in VS2013. error is in date when select 10 or above  but if date is below 10 then work fine.

```
$('#btnSaveInternalMeeting').bind('click', function () {

            if ($('#IMeetingDate').val() == "") {
                alert('Please select date.');
                return false;
            }

            var InternalCaller = "", InternalMeetingAttendees = "";
            $('.removeInternalCaller').each(function (i, obj) {
                InternalCaller += $(this).attr('tag') + ",";
            });

            if (InternalCaller.length < 2) {
                alert('Please select atlest one attendees...');
                return false;
            }

            $('.removeInternalAttendees').each(function (i, obj) {
                InternalMeetingAttendees += $(this).attr('tag') + ",";
            });

            if (InternalMeetingAttendees.length < 2) {
                alert('Please select atlest one attendees...');
                return false;
            }
            if ($('#btnSaveInternalMeeting').val() == 'Save') {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "MeetingArrangements.aspx/SaveInternalData",
                    data: "{'MeetingOn':'" + $('#IMeetingDate').val() + "' ,'MeetingStatus':'" + $('#ddlIMeetingStatus option:selected').text() + "' ,'CallersVRTeam':'" + InternalCaller + "' ,'AttendeesVRTeam':'" + InternalMeetingAttendees + "'}",
                    context: document.body,
                    success: function (responseText) {
                        var data = $.parseJSON(responseText.d);
                        alert('Save successfully!');
                        $('#btnSaveInternalMeeting').attr('tag', responseText.d);
                        $('#btnSaveInternalMeeting').val('Update');
                        $('#InternalMeetingAgendaTaskTable').show();
                        $('#Mail').show();
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "MeetingArrangements.aspx/UpdateInternalData",
                    data: "{'MeetingOn':'" + $('#IMeetingDate').val() + "' ,'MeetingStatus':'" + $('#ddlIMeetingStatus option:selected').text() + "' ,'CallersVRTeam':'" + InternalCaller + "' ,'AttendeesVRTeam':'" + InternalMeetingAttendees + "' ,'IMeetingId':'" + $('#btnSaveInternalMeeting').attr('tag') + "'}",
                    context: document.body,
                    success: function (responseText) {
                        var data = $.parseJSON(responseText.d);
                        //$(this).attr('tag', data);
                        alert('Update Successfully!');
                        $('#btnSaveInternalMeeting').attr('tag', responseText.d);
                        $('#InternalMeetingAgendaTaskTable').show();
                        $('#Mail').show();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: what is the error and where does it occur? Wouldn't you think providing the details might help people help you?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)
http://localhost/vmis/MeetingArrangements.aspx/SaveInternalData

but the same thing when i debug in VS 2013 it work fine

Comment: Inspect the request to see what is sent and if it is what you expect. You obviously have a problem with your server code handling whatever is sent. There are numerous debugging steps you can take. It doesn't seem you are doing many of them

Comment: Server side is just receive in web method as string and pass to function without converting but now error look like this 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token T '

Comment: when is give date below 10 it works fine but error when select date above 10.

Comment: What you are writing is meaningless other than you are sending garbage to the browser